# How can i sign APK With Upload Cert

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing

i have Enrolled my app in Google's (App signing).

so now i Got a :

1: App signing certificate .der

2: Upload certificate .der

so what now ?

how do i use the UploadCert.der to sign APK and Push update ?
and what do i do with my old SigningKey.jks that i used to sign my app with !

i thought i should use it in Android studio when i generate APK . so that didn't work.

[ScreenShot from My Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzAC5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should sign your APKs with the keystore you created when generating the upload certificate you uploaded to Play Console.

Note that the .der files that Play Console allow you to download are only the certificates, they don't contain the private key to sign anything. Although you have uploaded the app signing private key, only you has the upload private key. If you can't find the keystore, you can contact Play support team and ask to regenerate a new upload key.

Comment: i have used PEPK Tool to encrypt my .jsk file and output is .pem which i have uploaded to Play console .. so i should use .pem file !

Comment: No. The output of PEPK isn't a PEM file, and that was the keystore (.jks) of the *app signing* key. Based on your screenshot, it looks like you have also created another keystore for the *upload key* and you must have ran some other command (from keytool) which created a PEM file. Use that second keystore to sign your APK (note: the PEM does not contain your private key so is useless for signing).

Comment: i was trying to output .jks but for some reason it didn't work . so i so on online i should use .pem .. so i did .. and it worked .. Play console Accepted it .. so what i tried now .. is just to use my old Signing cert to sign APK and i uploaded it for a test and it worked ! i didn't get any error from Play Console . so now then what's the point of Enrolling in App signing .. im using my old Cert either way !

Comment: There are two purposes to App Signing: 1) if you upload an [Android App Bundle](https://g.co/androidappbundle) instead of an APK, Google Play can serve more optimized APKs to the developers. 2) if you lose your "old" keystore, you won't have to recreate a new app because Google will have a copy of it so you can keep updating your app.